# Server Browser like Game-Monitor.com

Tags: java, php, gwt

I want to make a server browser like http://game-monitor.com . Help me out in finding answers to the following questions:

1. where to start -- PHP or Java?
2. Can I display `Latency/Ping` with servers?
3. Is it possible to make using GWT (Google Web Toolkit)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [php sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) to measure server latency, and get data from the server. Depending on the type of game server (unreal engine ect.) There are php libraries written to do this, such as [php server query](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=964&lngWId=8) ( A bit old but should at least give you a good idea). They get the response and parse it to get the information for users, current map ect.

I'm sure all of this is possible using Java as well I just personally have never tried it.